# Increase Salesforce Workflow Email Limit?

Tags: email, workflow, email2case

Based on the Salesforce documentation, the Email Limit for Workflow is 1000 per user licence per day or 2,000,000 whichever is lower. We are currently exceeding that limit.

What I would like to know is if its possible to increase that limit from Salesforce? Has anyone ever heard about it or have done it?

In case it is not possible, what are the other options?

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to salesforce support asking to increase the limit? How many licenses do you currently have?

Comment: I have and the response hasn't been positive. Maybe because its just 1 license we have got as of now. Thats why I tried reaching out here to see if there is anyone who has it done.

Comment: If you have only one license (and I assume you've got multiple people sharing that one license, which is a violation of the terms of use and is grounds for salesforce.com canceling the contract) then it's probable that you're sending emails as some kind of workaround. Why do you need to send so many emails?

Comment: 1. Its a single person using the license as of now. And if the system turns out to be useful for them, more license purchase is planned. 2. We have Email2Case enabled as well as time based workflows. Cases created from Email2Case are forwarded to a set of email addresses for some type of Cases and that is taking the bulk of emails.

Answer (score 1):

That limit is not easy to raise. 
Why are you sending out so many emails? Is it to contacts (in which case you may wish to use an emailing tool like Exact Target) or is it some kind of integration tool to a single address? Some other thing?

If it is to one single address, then create a user with that email address and send unlimited emails to that user - because sending emails to users doesn't count against the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't increase or exceed these limits. Best is if you reach out to salesforce support and ask to increase the limit for your specific organization. It may cost you extra.